# redux-observable error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: redux, redux-observable

I am using redux-observable in my redux react app.  Given below is the code where I wire everything up.  I am using redux-dev tools as well.

```
const rootEpic = combineEpics(
    storeEpic
);

const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware(rootEpic);

//Combine the reducers
const reducer = combineReducers({
    syncSpaceReducer,
    routing: routerReducer
});

const loggerMiddleware = createLogger();
const enhancer = compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, loggerMiddleware, epicMiddleware),
    DevTools.instrument()
);

const store = createStore(reducer, enhancer);
```

My epic has the following code

```
export const storeEpic = action$ =>
    action$.ofType('FETCH_STORES')
    .mapTo({
        type: 'FETCHHING_STORES'
    });
```

Now when I run the app I get the following error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's possible for us to say. The code you provided all seems fine. The easiest way to know what's wrong is to look at the stack trace for that error. Where does it happen? What led up to it happening? Set a breakpoint there or use "Pause on exceptions" in your debugger to see what exactly is trying to call `apply` on a variable that is `undefined`--why is it `undefined`? That's ultimately the real question.

---

**Edit based on your comments.**

The problem is that what you're passing to `combineEpics` isn't actually your epic, it's `undefined`. Often that happens when your epic import has a typo or is not exported as you expect. Pause your debugger right before `combineEpics` and you'll see which one is undefined (or all of them).

Comment: This is the line where the error occurs

 var output$ = epic.apply(undefined, args);

epic is undefined when I try to debug.

Comment: @tmpdev I edited my answer above, the problem is one of the epics you're passing to `combineEpics` is not actually a function, it's undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Just import storeEpic in the file where combineEpics is called and it will work fine